# Windows - automatically log on user in the background?

Tags: windows, login, users

I want to set up my computer so that on startup a user account automatically logs on in the background, while the logon screen is still displayed so another user can be logged on and be able to switch to the first user with task manager. Is this possible?

I have done some Google searches and found that windows does have an auto logon feature but it is not in the background. The point of this is to prevent having to log out and log back in to another user. It is possible to create a startup script to log the user off as soon as it is logged on, but it could take a while as I have many other startup programs, defeating the purpose of this as time saving.

Another solution could be to create an RDP connection on startup, but that would mean the session would be in RDP mode even when it is switched to with task manager, and that has some problems such as no sound and no antialiasing.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if this is confusing/too much information.

Comment: Also, please don't give me "welcome to stack exchange" posts like you give to other new people, I know what website this is, I just need some help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. I think the closest to what you are looking for is using the "Switch User" option instead of the "Log Off" option. The "Switch User" option will not close network connections, and it will keep that user's session active.

Comment: I believe that all versions of Windows from Vista on refer to this process as "locking the workstation", rather than switching users. Of course, it's still the same basic idea, just a different name. PS: you can also do this using **Windows Logo** + **L**.

Comment: What I want is not to have to deal with logging off and onto another account. Switching user is exactly what I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not believe there is a way to do *exactly* what you are after you could get the same effect by simply closing your programs and putting your computer to sleep rather than shutting it down.

If you set it to sleep then it will either suspend to RAM or to the hard drive (Windows now does a "Hybrid Sleep" which does both so you get the best of both worlds) and will keep your user session almost immediately available.

If your resume settings are set up properly then this will also result in you being required to login, and as a result switch users, as well which seems to also fit your startup process.